# Is there a way to reference an "ipconfig" file in Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, powershell, command

So for a little context. In linux the "ifconfig" command is actually executing a "ifcfg-eth0" file found "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts."

In windows, do command line (or powershell) commands correspond to a specific file? If so where? If it exists I having a hard time finding it.

Reason:
I am trying to execute commands from a program I am writing in Python. I know there are other ways to accomplish this ie. "import os, import subproccess." I am trying to brainstorm a simpler way to execute these commands before my program gets to heavy.

Basically I would like to tell python to execute a file ie. "ifcfg-eth0" in linux but in windows. Also, I'm just using "ipconfig" as an example There are a lot of commands I want to add.

Comment: note that `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` is a convention used by some linux distributions (e.g. redhat) but not all (e.g. arch linux installs don't tend to use this).  `ifconfig` is a program that is commonly used across most distributions to configure network adapters, but it doesn't use those `sysconfig` files.  other scripts/programs read in the `sysconfig` files and in turn invoke `ifconfig` or the newer `ip` command to set up networking related features.

Comment: use `where.exe ipconfig` to find it.

Comment: Rather than call out to some program, why not use native python libraries to configure your interface?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, an easy way to find the path of a program is to use [Where.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html).

```
where.exe ipconfig
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually cmd commands are located in system32.
There's an executable ipconfig.exe in C:\Windows\system32